# Choose between AAX or VST

Tags: daw, ableton-live, vst, plugins

I am getting a plugin for Ableton Live named Spire which is a synthesizer. Should I get the AAX or VST version if I use Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VST, Ableton doesn't support AAX

https://help.ableton.com/hc/en-us/articles/209769405-Supported-Plug-in-formats

**Supported Plug-in formats**
VST 2 - 64 & 32-bit
Audio Unit (AU) - 64 & 32-bit

**Unsupported Plug-in formats**
VST 3
Audio Unit 3
Direct X
AAX
RTAS